# AutoMapper mapping for this specific scenario

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, tuples, return-value, automapper

I have this Converter class.

```
public class StatsConverter : TypeConverter<Tuple<Player,Stats>, StatsModel>
                                       , ITypeConverter<Stats, StatsModel>
{
    protected override StatsModel ConvertCore(Tuple<Player, Stats> source)
    {

        var pm = new StatsModel
            {
                Id = source.Item2.Id,
                PlayerId = source.Item1.Id,
                DisplayName = source.Item2.DisplayName,

            };
        return pm;
    }
}
```

How do I return a `IEnumerable<StatsModel>` in the following scenario where I have `List` ---- `player.PlayerStats` that needs to be mapped?

```
[HttpGet("{id:int}/PlayerStats", RouteName = "GetPlayerStats")]
public IEnumerable<StatsModel> GetPlayerStats(int id)
{
    var user = this._manager.GetPlayerById(id);

    // I can retrieve a "List" of player.PlayerStats. 
    //But how do I map and return it?
    return this._mapper.Map<IEnumerable<StatsModel>>(????)
}
```

When I do this

```
return this._mapper.Map<IEnumerable<StatsModel>>(player.PlayerStats);
```

I get this error:
`Change the type converter source type, or redirect the source value supplied to the value resolver using FromMember`.

Comment: What is the method signature of `_manager.GetPlayerById`?

Comment: Player GetPlayerById(int id);

Comment: You need a `Tuple<Player,Stats>` like you specified.

Comment: How do I implement the FromMember as specificed in the error message?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class StatsConverter : ITypeConverter<Tuple<Player, Stats>, StatsModel>
{
    public StatsModel Convert(Tuple<Player, Stats> source)
    {
        return new StatsModel
               {
                   Id = source.Item2.Id,
                   PlayerId = source.Item1.Id,
                   DisplayName = source.Item2.DisplayName,
               };
    }
}
```

First ensure your converter is specified.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Tuple<Player,Stats>, StatsModel>
      .ConvertUsing<StatsConverter>();
```

I'm going to assume from your question that the `Player` class is structured (correct me if I'm wrong):

```
public class Player
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Stats> PlayerStats { get; set; }
}
```

Inside your method you will need to get the player and stats grouped together.

```
var user = _manager.GetPlayerById(id);

// Expand the player stats
var playerStats = user.PlayerStats
                      .Select(stats => Tuple.Create(user, stats));

Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Tuple<Player,Stats>>,
           IEnumerable<StatsModel>>(playerStats);
```